# Android TextView not updating after relaunching app

Tags: android, textview

I'm developing an app which receives some values through sockets, and updates TextViews accordingly. I have a launcher activity which is finished when the user hits a start button to launch the "StatusUpdateActivity".

However, if I close the application (by hitting the back button), when I reopen it the TextViews won't update, even though this is printing fine:

```java
TextView tAvgLaneSpeed = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_avglanespeed);
Log.v("adas", "Textview text:  " + tAvgLaneSpeed.getText());
tAvgLaneSpeed.setText(avgLaneSpeed + " km/h");
Log.v("adas", "Textview text:  " + tAvgLaneSpeed.getText());
```

Produces:

```
V/adas﹕ Textview text:  23 km/h
V/adas﹕ Textview text:  20 km/h
```

Even though on the GUI the TextView is only showing the default text, " km/h".

The only solution I found is to manually terminate the app (using recent apps button and swiping right, for instance) or relaunch it via the IDE.

Any thoughts about this?

Full code on [github](https://github.com/jsvgoncalves/speed-limit-adas/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/jsvgoncalves/speedlimitadas/MainStatusActivity.java).

Comment: Post your complete code

Comment: My suggestion is to save in the sharedpreferences the value you receive from socket. So you save every time the last value and if you reopen the application you  will find the last correct result.

Comment: I've updated the question with a link to github. @End.Game even though this would show the last value, it would still not be updating to the current (constantly changing) values.

Comment: I suggest you update your textviews in the `onResume()` method

Comment: @joaquin actually the app terminates when I press the back button, so when I reopen the app I'm back at the launcher activity and I hit start again. The communication is still working, the getText() is still showing the correct values, but I do not see it on the GUI.

Comment: If you just hit the back button, the activity is still active but in background. So You should call finish() if You close the activity...

Comment: @Opiatefuchs so why am I taken back to the launcher activity when I reopen it? I'll then try to override the onBackPressed(). But it's still puzzling me why the GUI doesn't show what the getText() returns. Edit: even with the finish() the problem remains.

Comment: @JoãoGonçalves are you sure with the timing of the logs that they are not old? I think you look in the wrong way - also please read http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/starting.html

Comment: Are you calling setText() on the UI Thread? If not then call runOnUiThread(...);

Comment: @ligi yes, I just double checked it now.

Comment: @AdnanElezovic I'm running it on the UI thread

Comment: he must be on the UI-thread - otherwise it would just crash .. but the whole thing sounds really strange ..

Comment: @ligi the weirdest thing is that the getText() shows the correct text, but in the GUI there's no changes. And it's not frozen or anything (the menu bar is still clickable)

Comment: @JoãoGonçalves double check if you are looking at the right TextView ^^

Comment: @ligi Yeah, this is an overall problem, none of the TextView is being updated =\